# Using RegExp to filter messages in Logcat

Tags: android

i have an application in which i am using the tts engine. Some of its messages are getting logged and some from others classes. i am also writing some messages to log class.

But i want to filter the messages of tag "TtsService" which are only at  V-- Verbose level in eclipse logcat . How to do it? because i have studied that V is the lowest level , all others like I,D,W,E are at higher levels.so i am not getting how to filter those messages in eclipse logcat. when i use the TtsService tag all other messages at higher levels are also getting displayed.

i have seen in the logcat that it accepts  regular expressions, but i am not getting how to do it. if anybody tried this please throw some light on this problem.

Comment: one more doubt, if i need to write log messages to external text file, can it be opened in notepad later without any problem. please give me a suitable link to do this.i have tried but could not found any..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, regex won't help in this case. You may launch logcat from the command line and pass its output through a filter like [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep).